# I am getting error while running docker-compose up in Windows server 2016

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am getting the below error while running docker-compose up in **windows server 2016**.

docker compose version is **docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mujma.png)
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1244, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 966, in send
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 59, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

[4332] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the exact same symptoms. Turns out Docker wasn't running, and starting Docker solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker is probably not running on your machine. Just open Docker Desktop on your computer then go the Containers section to see if its running. If it is running, switch it off then go back to your project and run "docker-compose up --build "